# Spivak Calculus, Chapter 22, Problem 3

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

The answer book says that $\alpha \in [0,1]$ but I couldn't produce a good reasoning, in fact, all I could do was write the sequence as $a_n \in\{\frac{m}{n},\ \ 0 \lt m \lt n \}$ for a given $n$ but that isn't a well-defined function which makes for a useless construct.

Answer (score 1):

For any rational number $0<\frac p q<1$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ we have the subsequence

$$\frac p q,\frac {2p}{2q},\ldots,\frac {np}{nq} \to \frac pq$$

and

- $\frac1n \to 0$
- $\frac{n-1}n \to 1$

and since rationals are dense in the reals the result follows.

Refer to the related

- [What does it mean for rational numbers to be "dense in the reals?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1027970/505767)

Answer (score 0):

The given sequence is an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$, and the rational numbers are dense in $[0,1]$ so you can find a sequence which converges to any real number in $[0,1]$.