# Is there a Collatz 'branch' stopping time equation?

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, collatz-conjecture

Definitions:

-Collatz: odd: $\frac{3x+1}{2}$ | even: $\frac{x}{2}$

-Branch: Starting at an odd number and increasing until reaching an even number. Then decreasing until reaching another odd number (ex: 7,11,17,26,13 -> 4 steps).

Question:

As far as I'm aware, there is not an equation where one can plug in a specific starting number and get the stopping time of Collatz for that number, but is there a known equation that gives the stopping time for the first 'branch' of Collatz for a given number (or in the case of 5, the full stopping time)?

Comment: For $7$, would the function return $13$ (last number) or $4$ (number of steps)?

Comment: Im looking for something that would return 4 in the case of inputting 7.

Comment: one could use a computer and make a table (with $n$ and its stopping time), and look for patterns.

Comment: Letting $f(n)$ be the required function, it seems that $f(2^n-1) =$ [A093052](http://oeis.org/A093052)$(n)$.

Comment: Also $f(2^n-k) = c$, where $c$ is constant, $n \ge$ some value, and $k \ge 2$. For example $f(2^n-3) = 3$ for $n \ge 4$.

Comment: Are you asking for a formula? I dont understand what you mean by an equation in this sense.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy I didn't know there was a technical difference between the word equation and formula.  I've always used them interchangeably...

The scenario is: I have the number 7 and I want to know how many steps in Collatz before it reaches 13, I'm looking for an equation/function that when I plug in 7, it will equal 4.

I'm hoping this equation/function won't require me to know that 13 is the ending number in the sub-sequence.  Ideally it would only require me to input 7 as the only variable to make it equal to 4.

Comment: @JohnDNoone I think what you're looking for is similar to this [Closed-Form Solution](https://www.glynholton.com/notes/closed_form_solution/) or [Closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)

Comment: Just for reference: Ray Steiner called this form of trajectory (what you call "branch") in 1978 a "circuit" and investigated (and disproved) the possibility of *cyclic* "circuits" other than the trivial one $1 \to 2 \to 1 \to \cdots $ *(This should also be mentioned in wikipedia and is in all of Lagarias' overviews)* The cyclic form of this form of trajectory has also been called "1-cycle" by J. Simons/B.deWeger (who build on Steiner and extended btw.) The articles of Simons/deWeger are also online and easily accessible to ones who are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps:

It is well known and proven that any odd number can be written as $a\cdot2^k-1$ and reaches $a\cdot3^k-1$ (which is even) in exactly $k$ steps of the condensed Collatz function $\frac {3x+1}{2}$.

Than you need to divide by $2^n$ to get your final odd number (adding $n$ steps to the $k$ steps)

Now from here you can find the specific numbers that meet some criterias: You can target those specific numbers which divide by $2^n$ exactly to reach your target number (the one being odd), or you find the specific numbers for which the **stopping** point is reached (in this case the target number can still be even).

For the second case, there is a formula here (
[Showing $3^iq-2^{i-p}\neq2^pq-1$, with $p:=\lceil i\,\log_23\rceil$, $q:=\left\{\frac{2^{i}\,3^{2^{p-i-2}}}{2^p3^i}\right\}$, $i>6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338466/showing-3iq-2i-p-neq2pq-1-with-p-lceil-i-log-23-rceil-q-left)) 
But unless you prove the equality is not possible (this is the question of the post), you can't prove this is the stopping point (which needs strict inequality).