# Calculate the maximum in the Collatz sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, computational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

Consider the notorious Collatz function
$$ T(n) = \begin{cases}(3n+1)/2&\text{ if $n$ is odd,}\\n/2&\text{ if $n$ is even.}\end{cases} $$

One of the most important acceleration techniques of the convergence test is the usage of a sieve (test $k$ least significant bits of $n$, the sieve has the size of $2^k$ entries), and test only those numbers that do not join the path of a lower number in $k$ steps. This technique is greatly explained, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Modular_restrictions) or  [here](http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/techpage.html).

For example, consider the sieve for $k=2$ and particularly the numbers of the form $4n+1$ which join the path of $3n+1$ in two steps. Their path is
$$ 4n+1 \rightarrow 6n+2 \rightarrow 3n+1 \text{.}$$

What I don't understand is how this can be used to search for the highest number occurring in the sequence ([path records](http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/#part7) in the terminology of Eric Roosendaal). The sieve cuts the calculation before the computation of any intermediate value (which can actually be the maximum, like the value $6n+2$ in the above example). How can I detect that $4n+1$ does lead to a maximum if no $6n+2$ is computed? Testing the path of $3n+1$ no longer makes sense since the maximum $6n+2$ occurs before this term. Am I missing something?

Comment: $4n+1$ is not the best example since we are supposed to stop at 1 and not continue (and you would see N=1 Mx(N)=2 instead of N=2 Mx(N)=2 on Eric's page)

Comment: @Collag3n Consider for example the number 5 (which is of the form $4n+1$). Using the sieve with $k=2$ bits, the convergence test is skipped since the sieve indicates that the trajectory of this number joins a trajectory of a lower number in at most two steps (namely, the trajectory of the 5 joins the trajectory of 4 in two steps). This, however, results in a miss of the maximum (which is the number 8). Do I get it wrong? (The complete trajectory is 5 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1.)

Comment: 5 is not skipped in  sieve $k=2$ but in sieve $k>2$. But since 3 was already found with a greater path record (16), it is discarded.

Comment: And if 5 had reach another value higher then 8 later (with an higher $k$), it would have been found with 4 (well that's not the best example neither, you would have an odd value somewhere for that case)

Comment: The number of surviving residues $\mod ({2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}})$ is $s_i = s_{i-1}\cdot 2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil-\lceil (i-1) \log_23\rceil}-a(i)$ with $s_1=1$ and  where $a(i)$ is the $i^{th}$ term of this sequence https://oeis.org/A100982. Strangely Eric's page (http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/techpage.html) mention 1720 for $2^{16}$ where I find 2114. Do you know how he got this number?

Comment: $4n+1\to12n+4\to 6n+2\to 3n+1$ actually only intermediate steps are counted.

Comment: @Collag3n I also get 2114 out of 65536 numbers for $k=16$. I have no idea how Eric came to that number 1720. Just for the sake of interest, my implementation is [here](https://github.com/xbarin02/collatz-sieve).

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee This trajectory, however, does not correspond to my definition of  $T(n)$ in the question above.

Comment: I think your criticism is correct. For the conclusion for the filter being valid it must been proved elsewhere, that ***there is always*** a follower from $3n+1$ which is larger than the immediate follower of $4n+1$ (which is  $6n+2$). And I didn't see such a statement/proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Notation: residue $n_0\mod 2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}$ = residue $b\mod2^k$ from your wiki page)

**About the "discarded" 5 reaching maximum 8 (or 16), already reached by "surviving" 3:**

- One of the **discarded** sequence is the inverse V-Shape sequence which rise for $i$ steps of $f(x)=\frac{3x+1}{2}$ and then fall bellow the initial value by successive division by $2$ ([See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338466/showing-3iq-2i-p-neq2pq-1-with-p-lceil-i-log-23-rceil-q-left)). Of all discarded sequences $2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}n+n_0$ for a specific $n$, this is the type of sequence that potentially reaches the highest value: 
  $$(2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}n+n_0+1)\frac{3^i}{2^{i}}-1$$

Note: $n_0\leq 2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}-3$ and the exact value can be found in the link above

e.g. with $4n+1=5$ where $n_0=1$, $i=1$,$n=1$ which reaches $8$ before dropping to $4<5$

- One of the **surviving** sequence is the straight line which rise for the whole $k={\lceil i \log_23\rceil}$ steps of $f(x)=\frac{3x+1}{2}$. Of all surviving sequences for a specific $n$, this is the sequence (starting from $2\cdot2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}n-1$) that reaches the highest value (limited to $k={\lceil i \log_23\rceil}$ steps): 
  $$3^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}(n+1)-1$$

Note: here we always have $n_0= 2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}-1$

e.g. with $4n+3=7$ where $i=1$,$n=1$ which reaches $17$ (in 2 steps), or with $n=0$: $3$ reaches $8$

> Now it is easy to show that the highest value that can be reached by a discarded sequence at $n$ is smaller (or equal) than the highest value already reached by a surviving sequence at $n-1$

e.g with discarded $4(1)+1=5$ reaches $8$ which was already reached by surviving $4(1-1)+3=3$

Surviving highest value at $n-1$ is greater then discarded value at $n$?

$$3^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}n-1 \geq (2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}n+n_0+1)\frac{3^i}{2^{i}}-1$$
and with $n_0< 2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}-1$, we just need to show that
$$3^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}n-1 \geq (2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}(n+1))\frac{3^i}{2^{i}}-1$$
$$\Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big)^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}n \geq \Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big)^i(n+1)$$
$$\Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big)^{\lceil i \log_2\frac{3}{2}\rceil} \geq 1+\frac{1}{n}$$
which is already true for $n-1=0$ when $i\geq 3$ (manually checked for $i=1$ and $i=2$ by using the exact value of $n_0$ in those cases)

e.g. with $n-1=0$: discarded $32n+23$ reaches $188$ but surviving $32(n-1)+31$ already reached $242$

Note: you can multiply both side by 2 to get the "real" maximum (16 instead of 8).

The key idea is that even if the discarded inverse V-Shape at $n$ was at the highest possible residue $n_0= 2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}-3$, it would reach a smaller value than the straight line at $n-1$ (always with residue $n_0= 2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}-1$).

> This means that record paths are always found in residue $b\mod2^k$ (in other word, at $2^k\cdot n+b$ with $n=0$)

**EDIT:**

even more, when sieving $2^{k+1}$: values below $2^k$ that are dropping cannot produce new path records (obviously), but value above $2^k$ that are not surviving after $2^{k+1}$ sieve are now known, and there maximum is still the RHS above:
indeed the condition $n_0+2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}< 2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil+1}-1$ or  $n_0< 2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}-1$ do not change, and the value of $i$ (climbing steps) neither since the last step was a drop bellow initial value.

So even if the max value on the LHS do not climb anymore at step $k+1$, it would still be higher (the whole equation would stay the same).

> This means that new record paths are only found in **surviving** residue $b\mod2^k$

No need to check discarded residue at all, even within the sieve range.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106469/discussion-on-answer-by-collag3n-calculate-the-maximum-in-the-collatz-sequence).

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I found another [path record](http://pcbarina.fit.vutbr.cz/path-records.htm) while searching the interval up to 2^68. It is also mentioned [here](http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/pathrecs.html).

Comment: @DaBler, Nice :) there is another sieve I am interested in (https://oeis.org/A005184) but I am currently on something else, so they are both in my "To do" list until I find some time

Comment: These values seem to be very rare. I have found no more terms below $2^{44}$.

Answer (score 5):

Quote: "As $k$ increases, the search only needs to check those residues $b$ that are not eliminated by lower values of $k$"

Take residue 15 for instance. It survives $\mod 2^5$ but is eliminated while sieving $2^7$ so any value $x\equiv 15 \mod 2^7$ will not be searched anymore for $k>7$

Residue 15 was eliminated because it reached a lower value then himself $\mod 2^7$. It means that these numbers can't reach higher values, later with $k>7$, that were not reached (with a smaller $k$) by the lower value they just hit.

Comment: sorry for the poor wording, I am bit lazy on this one

Comment: The real acceleration, is noting that $2^mx+j$ has the parity of $j$ This means it will follow the same style of path as $j$ does ( only for $m$ steps, and only if $m$ is greater than or equal to, the number of divisions by 2 in $j$'s sequence, let $x$ be odd) this shows: $$2048x+7\to 6144x+22\to 3072x+11$$$$\to 9216x+34\to 4608x+17\to 13824x+52$$$$\to 6912x+26\to 3456x+13\to 10368x+40$$$$\to 5184x+20\to 2592x+10\to  1296x+5$$ and 4 more steps, eventually landing on $243x+1=242x+(x+1)$.    the altered Collatz function would never hit the highest points.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. Can we stay on that example with the number 5 and $k = 2$? [The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Modular_restrictions) says that the sieve answers the question whether the number $n = a2^k+b$ should be tested for the convergence or not. Right so far?

Comment: So if $f^k(a2^k+b) < 2^k+b$ for all nonzero $a$, and this also holds for all $k'<k$, the number $a2^k+b$ can be skipped, okay?

Comment: Note that the acceleration using the identity $f^k(a2^k+b)=a3^{c(b)}+d(b)$ is another technique, usually used right after the above sieve.

Comment: Perhaps one attempt to understand: Does the sieving with $k$-sieve imply that the maximum was already found before (for lower $n$ which was not eliminated by this sieve)?

Comment: I see no response in last 2 days, so let me add a few of my findings. Empirically, I have found that using sieves for gradually increasing $k$ will miss no maximum. More preciselly, the sieve for a particular $k$ doesn't miss any maximum above $2^k$, but can miss maxima below this threshold. So I believe your answer is correct, though informal (and I don't fully understand it). If you could explain it better, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Sorry, had not much time these days. I don't know if there is a formal proof no new path records can be found there (I am interested if someone knows one), but if you want to be sure from a sieve perspective, since the maximum value that can be reach by a residue $\mod (2^k={2^{\lceil i \log_23\rceil}})$ is smaller than $3^i$, if you keep track of your path records, you know up to what $k$ you are "safe", and I think these safety margins are growing. Now I didn't gave it much thought. Perhaps you'll find some answers in Oliveira's paper

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220577131_Maximum_excursion_and_stopping_time_record-holders_for_the_problem_Computational_results

Comment: smaller than $3^i\cdot 2^{k-i}$...sorry

Comment: Yet one another finding: This property also holds in the case of using a $3^k$ sieve (as opposed to $2^k$), e.g. numbers $n \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ can be skipped, etc.

Comment: Yes, I saw that too in Oliveira's paper at the end. That's probably why Eric got 1720 instead of 2114 for his $2^16$ sieve

Comment: No, that is no the reason for 1720. I have asked about it directly Eric. Quoting from his answer: "_that can not be shown to either converge or **join** the path of a lower number [...] The keyword is ‘join’ here. [...] So after calculating 2^16+x, for x=0 to 65535, compare all the results of  3*b + c (including the convergent ones)_"
If two of them are equal, discard the higher one." And I can confirm that using this method, I have really got number 1720 out of 65536.

Comment: For the case you want to play with Eric's idea, my implementation and pre-calculated sieves are available here: https://github.com/xbarin02/collatz-sieve