# how to solve modulo maths problems?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, collatz-conjecture

[preface, i'll use '%' as the modulo or remainder operator, as it is in C and many other programming languages, where for example 10 % 7 == 3]

i'm looking for an algorithm to solve for n in

```
(A*n + B) % C == 0
```

where A, B, and C are all positive integers.

i have additional constraints on my particular problem that i don't think are important for the solution.  (namely, A is less than C, A is a power of 3, C is a power of 2, and B is odd, all of which i believe imply that n must be odd.) (and yes, i'm toying with Collatz here)

i can brute force this (try all possible n from 0 to C-1), but that will become time consuming as C increases.  i could also try to binary search for it, which would be a performance improvement, but i'm looking for a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: You'll find some code optimization here, and code in the comments/chat: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454674/calculate-the-maximum-in-the-collatz-sequence

Comment: See the linked dupes for the standard theory and algorithms for solving linear congruences.

Answer (score 0):

Translating to more standard number theory, you want a solution to
$$
An\equiv-B\pmod C
$$
The first step to a solution is to solve
$$
Am\equiv 1\pmod C
$$
We then get $n=-Bm$ by multiplying both sides with $-B$.

The extended Euclidean algorithm gives you two integers $m, m'$ such that
$$
Am+Cm'=1
$$
(as your additional constraints tell us that $\gcd(A,C)=1$). This finishes the solution. A solution between $0$ and $C$ is not guaranteed in this case, so taking $n\%C$ at the end will give you that.

Comment: But the first step fails if $A$ and $C$ are not coprime. But not to worry since this is  FAQ which has been answered hundreds of times in the past. *Please* strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: @BillDubuque This time I actually _did_ a rudimentary search for dupes and still didn't find any good ones. Please stop hounding me about it, I have decided it is impossible. (I'm sure some can do it, but I just can't.)

Comment: so... any clues on how to do the first step (Am == 1 (mod C) ???

Comment: @GorillaSapiens Yes, the extended Euclidean algorithm, as I said.