# For calculating Collatz class records, how is the sieve constructed and used?

Tags: collatz-conjecture, sieve-theory

I'm looking at the [class record algorithm here](http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/techpage.html). I understand how some of the numbers (e.g. 8*k+5) can be skipped because they join with a lower number. But I don't understand exactly how the sieve of 2^25 elements that he refers to is constructed or used.

How exactly would one build the sieve and use it when calculating class records?

Comment: You could check this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454674/calculate-the-maximum-in-the-collatz-sequence there are also some code in it (https://github.com/xbarin02/collatz-sieve)