# Is this argument valid for showing given integers $n>1$ and $2^m > 3^n$, $(2^m - 3^n) \nmid 3^n - 2^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

It occurred to me that this might be straight forward to prove.  I wanted to check if my reasoning was correct.

I will be glad if anyone points out a mistake or a simpler, more general way to make the same argument.

Let:

- $m > 1, n> 1$ be integers
- $2^m > 3^n$

Claim:

$(2^m - 3^n) \nmid (3^n - 2^n)$

Argument:

(1)  $2^m - 3^n \ne 3^n - 2^n$ since:

- Assume $2^m - 3^n = 3^n - 2^n$
- $2^n(2^{m-n} + 1) = 2\cdot3^n$
- which is impossible for $n > 1$

(2)  Assume that there exists an integer $a>1$ such that:

$$a(2^m - 3^n) = 3^n - 2^n$$

(3)  It follows that:

$$a(2^n(2^{m-n} - 1)) + a2^n - a3^n = 3^n - 2^n$$

$$a(2^n(2^{m-n} - 1)) = (a+1)(3^n - 2^n)$$

(4)  But then:

$$(2^n(2^{m-n} - 1)) = \frac{a+1}{a}(3^n - 2^n)$$

which is impossible

---

Edit:

I missed the case where $2^n | (a+1)$.  If I can find an argument against this case, I will post it.  Otherwise, my argument is incomplete.

Comment: Your example supports the claim that $2^m - 3^n$ does not divide $3^n - 2^n$.  $55$ does not divide $5$.

Comment: Take the sum of the quotient and show it diverges?  $r=1$ if it's geometric.

Comment: @floorcat could you provide additional details.  It sounds interesting.  I am not clear how it would work.

Comment: Is there a typo?  Did you mean $2^m-3^n|3^m-2^n$?

Comment: @fleablood I meant $2^m - 3^n$ divides $3^n - 2^n$.  It is one of those points that seems like it is easy to prove but then it's not.  $2^5 - 3^3 = 5$ is less than $3^3 - 2^3 = 19$

Comment: @LarryFreeman FYI, your question is somewhat related to the [Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#Generalization) section of Wikipedia's "Catalan's conjecture" article, i.e., the "... conjecture that for every natural number $n$, there are only finitely many pairs of perfect powers with difference $n$". If true, this means there's only a relatively limited # of small values which $2^m - 3^n$ can take, indicating any counter-example may be difficult to find and, if it any exist, will quite likely involve very large $2^m$ and $3^n$ values.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, So, an argument, if it exists, could well be significantly involved. Thanks. I always find it interesting when what appears to be a simple problem is actually related to a deeper mathematical problem

Comment: @LarryFreeman If you can represent the quotient as a geometric series, the value of r which stands for the distance between terms is equal to 1, and thus the series diverges.  I'm just spit balling ideas here, this may not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you narrow your question to Collatz cycles (which I suspect to be the case), that is a question I asked myself (see EDIT point here: [Showing $3^iq-2^{i-p}\neq2^pq-1$, with $p:=\lceil i\,\log_23\rceil$, $q:=\left\{\frac{2^{i}\,3^{2^{p-i-2}}}{2^p3^i}\right\}$, $i>6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338466/showing-3iq-2i-p-neq2pq-1-with-p-lceil-i-log-23-rceil-q-left)) in the case of a non-trivial "1-cycle" of the Collatz conjecture. Note that this adds an additional constraint on $m$.

To have a one cycle you start at odd $a = b2^n - 1$, you climb up to $b3^n - 1$ and than divide by $2^{m-n}$ to reach $a$ again:

$$b2^n - 1=\frac{b3^n - 1}{2^{m-n}}$$

In other words $$a=\frac{(a+1)\frac{3^n}{2^n}-1}{2^{m-n}}$$
or $$a(2^m-3^n)=3^n-2^n$$

In a cycle, $\frac{3^n}{2^m}<1$ and with the above formula we can write

$$0 < \frac{2^m}{3^n} - 1 = \frac{2^{m-n} -1}{b3^n} = \frac{2^{m-n} - 1}{2^{m-n}(b2^n - 1) + 1} < \frac {1}{2^n}$$

For an $x>1$ you have $0<\log x<x-1$ so you can write the above formula as

$$0 < m \log 2 - n \log 3 < \frac{2^m}{3^n} - 1 < \frac {1}{2^n}$$

But with the Rhin bound: $|m\log 2 - n\log 3| > 0.00218n^{-13.3}$ and some manual check (for $n<96$ as shown by Steiner in 1977), we can see this is not possible ($2^m-3^n\nmid3^n-2^n$ at least with the additional constraint on $m$)

Comment: you read my mind.  This question is within the context of the Collatz Conjecture.  :-)  Thanks very much for your answer.