# Can there be integer solutions (please PROVE)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers, collatz-conjecture

With the following equation-
$\frac{(3^x-2^x)}{(2^{(x+y)}-3^x)} = z   $
What $x,y,z$ (all integers) satisfy this?
The trivial solutions are-
$X=1,y=1,z=1 ,X=2,y=1,z=-5   ,X=1,y=0,z=-1   $

This is my own “restatement” of the impossibility of the $k=1$ cycle for collatz sequences and it would be incredibly helpful if someone could prove it in this form (it should be possible to prove that no integer solutions for $x,y,z$ exists other than the trivials)

Comment: Perhaps this discussion of mine suffices: https://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_1cycledisproof.pdf . I'm applying the approximation-bound given by G. Rhin (see also the answer of @Collag3n)

Answer (score 3):

A ["1-cycle" in Collaz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3862457/is-this-argument-valid-for-showing-given-integers-n1-and-2m-3n-2m/3866590#3866590) implies

$$\frac{2^m}{3^n} - 1 < \frac {1}{2^n}$$
$$2^m-3^n < (\frac {3}{2})^n$$
$$2^m-3^n < 1.5^n$$

but from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4022134/show-that-2n2-lceil-n-log-23-rceil-3n3n-2n/4044330#4044330) we know that ($n>5$)

$$2^m-3^n \ge 2^{\lceil n \cdot log_2(3)\rceil}-3^n>  2^n$$
$$2^m-3^n >  2^n>1.5^n \implies \text{contradiction}$$

So for the value of $m=x+y$ and $n=x$ that you consider (Collatz cycle where $m$ is believed to be equal to $\lceil n\cdot log_2(3)\rceil$), and outside the exception for $n=1$, we have

$$2^m - 3^n \nmid 3^n - 2^n$$

**EDIT**

Another approach for the first part in the context of a 1-cycle ($a,b$ from the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3862457/is-this-argument-valid-for-showing-given-integers-n1-and-2m-3n-2m/3866590#3866590)):
$$\frac{3^n-2^n}{2^m-3^n}=a=b\cdot2^n-1\ge2^n-1$$
$$\implies 2^m-3^n \le \frac{3^n-2^n}{2^n-1}<\frac{3^n}{2^n}$$
$$\implies 2^m-3^n < 1.5^n$$

For negative values, use the same reasoning (but here $2^m<3^n$):

$$\frac{3^n-2^n}{2^m-3^n}=a=-b\cdot2^n-1\le -2^n-1$$
$$\implies 2^m-3^n \ge \frac{3^n-2^n}{-2^n-1}$$
$$\implies 3^n-2^m \le \frac{3^n-2^n}{2^n+1}<\frac{3^n}{2^n}$$
$$\implies 3^n-2^m < 1.5^n$$

but from the same [link above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4022134/show-that-2n2-lceil-n-log-23-rceil-3n3n-2n/4044330#4044330) ($n>2$ and $m$ is smaller than $\lceil n\cdot log_2(3)\rceil$)

$$2^{m+1}-3^n\le2^{\lceil n\cdot log_2(3)\rceil}-3^n<3^n-2^n$$
$$2\cdot 2^m-2\cdot 3^n<-2^n$$
$$3^n-2^m>2^{n-1}>1.5^n \implies \text{contradiction}$$

with the exception you found for $n\le2$

Comment: I’m sorry what are m and n in this?

Comment: @Charlie D. ,I used the notations from the links, but m=x+y and n=x

Comment: @Charlie D. , I hope the edit clarify what is in the link. In short, in the context of a 1-cycle, there is no value of $m\ne2$ allowing an integer solution to your fraction. Note that it does not mean there is no possible integer solution outside this context (when there is no constraint on $m$), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#Generalization

Comment: Sorry but this form has y as the number of divisions of two in the cycle, so if there is integers solutions outside that would be a spanner in the works.

Comment: @Charlie D. in the context of a 1 cycle, $y$ is determined by $x$ ($y>=\lceil x\cdot log_2(\frac{3}{2})\rceil$), and with this constraint, there is no integer solution has shown. Outside the 1-cycle context (y can be anything), nobody knows if there is an integer solution or not, but this is not important if you are only interested in the 1-cycle context. 1 cycle forces $\frac{3^n-2^n}{2^m-3^n}\ge2^n-1$ which is needed to prove your point. Why not use it?

Comment: Oh wow I was confused before but this makes sense thanks!