# Collatz stopping time curves

Tags: stopping-times, collatz-conjecture

We define the Collatz stopping-time of an integer $n$ to be the number of iterations of the [Collatz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) on $n$ untill we reach $1$. A corollary of the Colatz conjecture is that this time is finite for all $n$.

This is a plot of the stopping-time for numbers up to $10^4$.

[image: Collatz stopping time plot]

The plot seems to consist of a family of decreasing curves. Is there a known formula for these curves?

Answer (score 1):

considering that the stopping time=$\lceil \log_2(6^i\cdot n)\rceil$ (with $i$ the number of odd steps), you should have these k-family of curves:
$$f(k,n)=\log_{\frac{8}{9}}(6^{5-k}n^5)$$

e.g. with $k=30$
[image: e.g. k=30]

You can try here [SageMath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=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&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: Thanks! Can you link to a source?

Comment: @Rd Basha, I don't know if this has already been studied. I just used the (unproven) stopping time formula $st\sim i\cdot log_26 + \log_2n$ and the above plot in logarithmic form (using $\log_2n$ instead of $n$ axis) and transposed to a non-logarithmic plot

Comment: Do you have a source for the unproven stopping time formula? Where does it come from? Just numerical fitting?

Comment: @Rd Basha, Same thing. I am not sure it exists somewhere (Perhaps Lagarias paper), but it comes from $3^i\Big(1+\frac{1}{3n_0}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{1}{3n_1}\Big)\cdots\Big(1+\frac{1}{3n_{i-1}}\Big)=\frac{n_i}{n_0}\prod_{j=1}^i2^{k_j}$ that you can find here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3212129/a-possible-way-to-prove-non-cyclicity-of-eventual-counterexamples-of-the-collatz/3215501#3215501 where you just take the $log_2$ of both sides and you end up with $k_1+k_2+k_3+\ldots+k_i=i\cdot \log_23+\log_2{n_0}+\log_2\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}\Big(1+\frac{1}{3n_j}\Big)$ ...

Comment: ... then with $k$ the sum of $k_j$: $k=\lceil i\cdot \log_23+\log_2{n_0} \rceil$ knowing that $st=k+i$. It relies on the fact that the "+1" terms never exceed $3^i n_0$

Comment: but the last sentence of the above comment is unproven