# Prove that every point of $f(x)$ is on a linear function

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x)$ is continuous on [0,1]. Every point $(x,f(x)), x\in \Bbb Q$ is on the linear function $y=(f(1)-f(0))x+f(0)$.
Prove that every point $(r,f(r))$ (when $r$ is irrational) is on this linear function.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is essentially equivalent to this one:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions with $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Show that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Obviously, the continuity condition is really important.  The other property that's used is the [density](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027970/what-does-it-mean-for-rational-numbers-to-be-dense-in-the-reals) of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.